# How to start an activity from a non-activity class (which implements IntentService)?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications, message

I have a class which processes messages received from the cloud, this class extends IntentService. For now messages (bundle extras) are put inside a notification. But I need to start and pass these extras to another activity (dialogActivity) which prompts the user to take action and then then displays the full message.

The only way I could start a new activity from inside this class was to add FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to the intent which starts it. But in this case messages overlap each other, I mean new messages are not shown because of this flag which stops the activity to start a new task while another is already opened.

I cannot use other flags either because my app crashes and Logcat suggests to use FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK to avoid further crashes.

Is there any other way to start my "dialogActivity" from within this class?

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't start an `Activity` from a `Service` - it doesn't lend itself to good UX and users wont thank you for it.

Comment: @Squonk - I need to show the message to the user (who is basically a driver) and to offer the chance to approve or cancel a request shown in the message/dialog. Notifications are not ok because is too complicated and time consuming.